# Grid Graphics Representation Problem in R-Studio

Tags: r

I am working with that [book](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epaul/RGraphics/chapter5.pdf) and `R-Studio`. I tried to render a grid graphic as described in the book:

```
library(grid)

pushViewport(plotViewport(c(5, 4, 2, 2)))
pushViewport(dataViewport(pressure$temperature,pressure$pressure,name="plotRegion"))



grid.points(pressure$temperature, pressure$pressure,name="dataSymbols")
grid.rect()
grid.xaxis()
grid.yaxis()

grid.text("temperature", y=unit(-3, "lines"))
grid.text("pressure", x=unit(-3, "lines"), rot=90)

grid.edit("dataSymbols", pch=2)

upViewport(1)
grid.rect(gp=gpar(lty="dashed"))
downViewport("plotRegion")
grid.text("Pressure (mm Hg)\nversus\nTemperature (Celsius)",x=unit(150, "native"), y=unit(600, "native"))
```

When running that code, it looks like the following:
[image]

According to the book, the result should look like this

[image]

What do I wrong? Was also running `dev.off()` without any effect....

I have access to the dataset `pressure`